# JQuery and Jtools

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Jquery Tools and Jquery. I include the 2 libraries separately.
I have chosen to use the Jquery tools effect: 
Overlay: Loading External Pages Into Overlay.

( I am a new user on stack overflow so I get 1 hyperlink per post- i saved it for below)

The tool works beautifully in firefox and chrome.  the css for the overlay simply falls apart when viewed in IE 7,8.  In these IE versions the overlay div appears way at the bottom of the page.  while the close button appears in the top right corner- both of these elements are far from the positions they take in firefox and chrome.

(Amazingly the CSS works pretty well in IE 6)

I have spent days on this.  I really need help. 
my site: 
http://www.digitall-productions.com/Grlib/pages/Events.php

Comment: if you want to solve IE problems easily, try learning how to create clean and valid markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place div tags in your head tag. Start with valid HTML markup, see http://validator.w3.org/ to show you where your issues are. Once you can validate your markup then start with jQuery and other additions.